# Visualforce - Add Check Mark

Tags: visualforce, community

How can I add check marks with a button?  As user complete their section, it will show a check mark or an "X".  Please see link for a screenshot: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s197/sh/8283848c-86d2-4945-bdd4-e8e85e34b949/6b62b17ff9e92c6c653a06bcd76cdf98

Any suggestion or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've updated my answer and made the output much nicer. Unfortunately, I don't think you'll be able to use a commandbutton for this UI, but you can get around this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use fontawesome for this. You can easily create buttons like this:

[image]

The code for this looks like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" href="#">Done
    <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i></a>

<a class="btn btn-warning" href="#">Not Done
    <i class="fa fa-close fa-lg"></i></a>
```

You can add this class to anything you like - it can be a styleClass on a commandButton - anything you like.

The final piece of the puzzle is including fontawesome in the header of the page:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**EDIT** 
If you need to turn on an off these button styles, it may be easier to wrap a version of each inside an `outputPanel` for each tab:

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!Account.SomeBooleanField__c}">
    <a class="btn"  style="background:LightBlue;padding:8px;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block" href="#">Done
        <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg"></i></a>
</apex:outputPanel>
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!NOT(Account.SomeBooleanField__c)}">
    <a class="btn"  style="background:Crimson;padding:8px;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block"  href="#">Not Done
        <i class="fa fa-close fa-lg"></i></a>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Do you happen to know how to make this dynamic?  If a user input box is blank than display "Not Done X".  If user input box is filled in then display "Done".

Comment: How do I use this in my button?  <apex:commandButton value="Overview" action="{!overview}" style="background:LightBlue;width:149px;height:49px;"/><br/>

Comment: You are using a commandButton? I've been experimenting and I think you'll have to use the `<a>` tag as shown above in combination with an actionfunction (the `<a>` tag has an onclick that calls the actionfunction, which in turn calls the action on the controller)

Comment: Ok, try my latest version - I've added inline styles that will make the `<a>` tag look very pretty.